# Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe Error with PyQt5 when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am using PyQt5 to convert a local html file into pdf. The executable was working fine before the pyqt5 module was added. However, now I get a 'could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe' error. I've read that the issue has been resolved in the later models but I am still experiencing this error. I have the latest version of anaconda and pyqt5.

I read a git thread that asked to use 5.9.2 version of pyqt but that did not solve the error either.

This is the command I'm using to create an executable:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --onefile Q:\Ray\test.py
```

Comment: don't use `--onefile` option with Qt as it usually causes these kinds of problems. Also try copying the libexec folder to the side of the executable, the libexec folder is in `.../site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/libexec`

Comment: @eyllanesc what do you mean by 'side of the executable'

Comment: pyinstaller generates an executable that is in the dist folder

Comment: That did not help either. Still getting the same error. Any other solutions?

Comment: Have you recompiled the script without the --onefile option?

Comment: Yes even without the onefile it doesn't work

Comment: Could you compile the following script https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/59157ab1c96f30471aa200e23e2e75d6 and tell me what you get in the console when running

Comment: also copy `QtWebEngineProcess.exe`  to the side of the executable.

Comment: By copying to the side of the executable, you mean the dist folder where the executable is created, right?

Comment: yes,  you are right

Comment: @eyllanesc FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\rachou\Desktop\\Ray\\dist\\log_custom.txt'

Comment: please change to  `with open(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "log_custom.txt"), "w") as f:`

Comment: Running the code before converting to executable: C:\Users\Raychou\Desktop\Ray>python main.py
C:\Users\Raychou\Desktop\Ray\index.html
LibraryExecutablesPath: C:/Users/Raychou/Anaconda3/Library/bin
finished test.pdf True

Comment: After converting to executable: C:\Users\raychoudh\Desktop\Ray\dist\main>main.exe
C:\Users\raychoudh\Desktop\Ray\dist\main\index.html
LibraryExecutablesPath: C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/bin
Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219831/discussion-between-ray234-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: copy QtWebEngineProcess.exe to C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/bin

Comment: @eyllanesc there's no such existing directory. Do I create one?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens if you have installed Python with Anaconda which has pyqt5 folder in `.../site-packages` but actually it's not a pip package and if you `pip show pyqt5` it outputs `Package(s) not found: pyqt5` so installing pyqt5:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

will do the trick. Since the above command installs the latest pyqt5 and Anaconda initially uses older versions make sure to run your app to test everything works fine then recompile your app using Pyinstaller and it will just work.

Hope this helps!